# additional button(s) to navigation bar in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, navigation

I can add a normal rightBarButton to my navigation without a problem but now I need an additional button next to the rightbarbutton..... same style :-)

And a still need to have the title in the navigation bar.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** my answer is about `UINavigationItem` (which exists as a property in every `UIViewController`) not an actual `UINavigationBar`. It's not 100% clear which one you're using.

You can set a button on a [`UINavigationItem`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) with the `SetRightBarButtonItem` method (or the `RightBarButtonItem` property).

If you want multiple buttons then you need to use `SetRightBarButtonItems` (not the 's') method (or the `RightBarButtonItems` properties).

**But be aware that this API is only available on iOS 5 and later.**

Comment: thx a lot! this did the job. regarding the iOS versions.... just of curiosity, do you know if there are any "official" numbers for how many users that use each iOS version?

Comment: I recall numbers (from an application developers) showing a very high percentage of people updating their iOS devices (it's free and Apple supports quite old hardware without too many feature restrictions). Sadly I don't have a link to it. Here's one I googled (from a web site logs) at http://www.game4mob.com/index.php/tech-articles/67-ios-5-penetration-percentage

Comment: thx a lot! I think I'll live with the fact that only iOS5 devices can use the app